# Merge schema of multiple parquet files in Glue DynamicFrame using Python

Tags: python, aws-glue, parquet

I want to read multiple parquet files(S3 source) with different schemas into a Glue DynamicFrame. I am unable to merge the schemas of the files. The first file's header is interpreted as the schema of the DynamicFrame. Only the columns that are matching with first file's are read from the other files. The rest of the columns are dropped. Is there a way to merge all the headers into a single one?

```
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

inputGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://bucket_name/"],"useS3ListImplementation":True, "recurse": True}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx="inputGDF")
```

Comment: There is the merge schema option in a Spark dataframe, but I want to use Glue bookmarking as well which is only available in a Glue dynamicframe.

Comment: You can convert `toDF()` after the initial read. Glue bookmark would still work in your `inputGDF`.

Comment: @lsc That is what I did. There is no other merge option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert the DynamicFrame to a Spark dataframe with the toDF() function.